# In Perl, why do I need to @b = @{dclone(\@a)}? Why can't I just @b = dclone(\@a)?

Tags: perl, arrays

I have an array of various things including scalars and arrays.  I want to make a copy of it, and tried the following:

```
@b = dclone(\@a)
```

but then when I try to read one of the scalar values from b, I get nothing back.

Everything appears to work when I copy it this way, though:

```
@b = @{dclone(\@a)}
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`dclone`](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.21/Storable.pm) takes and returns references.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use Storable qw/ dclone /;

my @array = ( [1 .. 3], qw/ apple orange banana / );
my $copy = dclone \@array;

print ref($copy), "\n";
```

The output of the program above is `ARRAY`, so to get a deep-cloned array, use

```
my @copy = @{ dclone \@array };
```

To show what was going on without the dereference, the output of

```
my @copy = dclone \@array;

for (0 .. 4) {
  print "$_: ",
        (defined $copy[$_] ? $copy[$_] : "<undef>"),
        "\n";
}
```

is

```
0: ARRAY(0x1d396c8)
1: <undef>
2: <undef>
3: <undef>
4: <undef>
```

So assigning the result of `dclone` to an array will produce a single-element array, and trying to fetch any value other than the zero-th yields the undefined value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference the return value of `dclone` which is a pointer (reference).

Answer (score 2):

As said by a couple people `dclone` takes and returns references. That's good enough, but I think there is also the question of *why?*

As the documentation for [`Storable`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable#Hooks) shows `dclone( ... )` is the equivalent of composition of `thaw` and `freeze` as `thaw( freeze( ... ))`. `thaw` can thaw *any* type of encoded structure. A reference can refer to anything in Perl. That array of hashes of arrays that you wanted, the hash of hashes of arrays, .... It relies upon *you* to know what you've asked for--and if not that at least for you to puzzle it out a little bit.

However, if you really dislike the syntax, and will be using the ARRAY -> ARRAY idiom enough to want to make it look better, you can write a wrapper function like so:

```
sub dclone_array (\@) { 
    use Storable 'dclone';
    my $in  = shift;
    my $out = dclone( $in );
    return @$out;
}
```

And use it like:

```
my @copy = dclone_array( @orig );
```